# What does "source:name" in filter means?

Tags: elasticsearch-curator

I have been studying curator past few days and I came across this filter type "age".
On official documentation it is written as name based age filter look for a timestring within the index or snapshot name, and convert that into an epoch timestamp.
Which is not quite clear to me.

If I mention

```
source: name
```

what "name" does curator refer to? 
Does it refer to name of any particular index and if yes how can I mention name of that index?

It will be really helpful if anyone suggest me some more documentation on curator.
Thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `source: name` reads the index name and looks for a time/date value matching `timestring`. For example, if you had an index named `indexname-2019.06.01`, you might build a filter like this:

```
- filtertype: age
  source: name
  timestring: ‘%Y.%m.%d’
  unit: days
  unit_count: 30
  direction: older
```

This filter (if not following other filters in a list) will look through the names of *all* indices in Elasticsearch for a `Year.month.day` pattern, convert it to an epoch time stamp, and see if that date is more than `30` `days` `older` than the epoch time stamp at the time Curator is executed. If that is true, that index name will remain in the actionable list to do whatever action the filter is associated with.

Now, this by itself can be a dangerous filter. It will match `indexname-2019.06.01` or `2019.06.01-anything` or even `prefix-2019.06.01-suffix`. Filters in Curator were made to go together in a chain. To specify which indices you want Curator to consider, it might be wise to do a `pattern` filter before the `age` filter:

```
- filtertype: pattern
  kind: prefix
  value: indexname
- filtertype: age
  source: name
  timestring: ‘%Y.%m.%d’
  unit: days
  unit_count: 30
  direction: older
```

Now this filter list will only look for indices which begin with `indexname` *and* have a `Year.month.day` time string after that. Filters in Curator are always ANDed together.

The official Curator documentation is the ultimate source of truth for all things Curator. If you have further requests for explanation, I’m happy to answer them (full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of Curator).

Comment: Thank you for simplifying it, it cleared most of my doubts! ^^